# $S = \{ A \in M_{n}(\mathbb{R}) : 0 <\operatorname{rank}(A) = p < n \}$ is a graph of a $C^{1}$ function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, tangent-spaces, submanifold

Consider $S = \{ A \in M_{n}(\mathbb{R}) : 0 < \operatorname{rank}(A) = p < n\}$, where p is a fixed integer.

Suppose that $n = 2$ and $p = 1$. Show that, locally, $S$ is the graph of a real $C^1$ function. Find the tangent plane of $S$ in
$$A_{0} = \pmatrix{
0 & 0\\
0 & 1
}$$

I don't have an interesting idea to prove this, maybe use the rank theorem, but I don't know how can I use it. Someone can help me? Thank you in advance

Comment: Huh?  You make $p<n$ and then suppose $n=p=1$?

Comment: Ahhh sorry, I make a mistake

Comment: What do you mean by "$S$ is locally the graph of a real $C^1$ function"?

Comment: At each point of $S$ there is a neighborhood of this point that will be a graph of a function

Comment: Have you seen the (local) submersion theorem?  If so, just compute the derivative of det at $A$ and show it is nonzero.  The tangent plane at $A_0$ is easily seen to be $\begin{pmatrix}0&*\\*&*\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: A $2\times 2$ matrix has rank $1$ exactly when at least one column is non-zero, and the other column is a multiple of the first. That is
$$S = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} cv & v\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} v & cv\end{bmatrix}\mid c \in \Bbb R, v \in \Bbb R^2, v \ne 0\right\}$$